# Failed n'th loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys for "tracks" key

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have a problem with AVFoundation. I have collections with mp4s, during the presentation of the cell I play the film. Before actual playing it I call AVURLAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys for the "tracks" key. After scrolling to ~234'th mp4 suddenly the tracks stop loading, the status is failed and the asset has empty tracks list (the asset is ok, checked by opening it as first mp4). When I commented out a part of the code, I discovered that if I wouldn't create AVAssetReader everything would load nicely while scrolling. Just one line of code which creates an AVAssetReader (without ever assigning it) causes a later loading problem. Slowly I lack ideas how to bite this problem

There is an error during loading as well but I it does not help much:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (1), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/584E5109-11CA-4759-A251-2D8FFC1D5A1C/Documents/videos/42A5847C-C948-402E-806C-861103F9B3E0/p1023/fullsize.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x175457ee0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by updating iOS from 10.2 to 10.3.3